# Getting Routing Error while submit the form using ROR

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I need one help. I am getting the following error while post the form data using ROR.

```
No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"

Rails.root: C:/Sites/blog
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
articles_path   GET     /articles(.:format)     articles#index
    POST    /articles(.:format)     articles#create
new_article_path    GET     /articles/new(.:format)     articles#new
edit_article_path   GET     /articles/:id/edit(.:format)    articles#edit
article_path    GET     /articles/:id(.:format)     articles#show
    PATCH   /articles/:id(.:format)     articles#up
```

I am explaining my code below.

> new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

date
```

When user is submitting this form those type of error is coming.My `route.rb` file is given below.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

My controller file code is given below.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new

    end
    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
    end
end
```

I am using Rails version `4.2...`.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: The default Rails `new` action would be `GET /articles/new`, but the default `create` action would be `POST /articles` (without the `/new` on the end); your form is being submitted to the wrong URL. By the way, shouldn't your `def new` controller method contain `@article = Article.new`?

Comment: Can you edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The default Rails `new` action would be `GET /articles/new`, but the default `create` action would be `POST /articles` (without the `/new` on the end); your form is being submitted to the wrong URL somehow.

To quickly re-create this scenario, I entered the following into a terminal:

```
rails new blog
cd blog
rails generate scaffold articles
rake db:migrate
rails s
```

... which created an Articles controller with the following `def new` method:

```
# GET /articles/new
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

I navigated to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/articles` in my browser before clicking "New Article" and then "Create Article"; no errors occurred.

However, removing the `@article = Article.new` line from `def new` (to match the controller code in your question) caused the following error to appear on the "New Article" page:

```
ArgumentError in Articles#new

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Extracted source (around line #1): <%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
```

I'm not sure how you managed to get far enough to see the `No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"` message, but I'd imagine that the missing `@article = Article.new` line has something to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by adding:

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```